# Какое может быть практическое обоснование такой комбинации switch и while?

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

На просторах сети нашел несколько "странное" применение конструкций языка. Вот небольшой пример, [который я набросал сам](http://ideone.com/LPlYOd), просто по "шаблону":

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void foo(const int i) {
  cout << "foo(" << i <<")" << endl;
}

int main() {
  int c = 10;
  switch(c&3) while((c-=4)>=0) {
    foo(c); case 3:
    foo(c); case 2:
    foo(c); case 1:
    foo(c); case 0:;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Специально для незнающих не раскрываю "мелочи", пусть будет интригой) От "знающих" прошу чисто **практический пример - и с объяснениями мелочей**. Почему сия конструкция иногда (или часто?) дает профит.

Comment: Давала. Когда-то. Когда оптимизаторы не умели разворачивать циклы...

Comment: @Majestio  Если память мне не изменяет, то этот вопрос задавали как раз вчера на enSO.:)

Comment: Кстати, в "Современном C++" Готтшлинга подобные раскрутки делаются через шаблоны, и там целое исследование, насколько такое выгодно. Вкратце - depends on... Общего правила нет. Одна и та же конструкция в одном случае может ускорять, в другом - тормозить.

Comment: Каков субъективный вывод?

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25592451/5000805

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Это по сути ручная размотка цикла, известная как [Duff's device](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B0). Сейчас она практически не нужна, так как современные компиляторы делают это сами, если считают нужным. (А «считать нужным» они умеют намного лучше нас.)

Для старых компиляторов имело смысл, т. к. позволяло сэкономить на управлении циклом, выполняя по нескольку итераций (в вашем случае — 4) за раз. Странный код с `switch` нужен, понятно, для того, чтобы правильно работал случай, когда длина цикла не кратна размеру размотки.

Comment: Можно пример для "старых" компиляторов? где и что экономилось... Ну и как поступают современные компиляторы (допустим на площадке https://gcc.godbolt.org)

Comment: @Majestio: Ну, на старых компиляторах у вас код `for` компилировался без размотки, прямо как есть, а значит, условие выхода из цикла проверялось на каждой итерации. С размоткой условие проверяется лишь каждые 4 итерации. Если тело цикла короткое, это _может_ принести пользу.

Comment: Влад, через 2 мин я смогу поставить вашему ответу зеленую галочку. И тем не менее .. прошу дополнить ваш ответ примером кода, где в цикле на 490 итераций используется эта методика. Просто дабы осознать степень своего неосознания)

Comment: @Majestio: Вот пример: https://godbolt.org/g/62uWx7

Comment: @Majestio: Там глубина размотки 6.

Comment: чет я немного теряюсь ... походу я вижу не тот код. Если можно - тож самое на ideone.com , чтоб выполнялось и выдавало результат.

Comment: @Majestio: Не, это был пример того, как _оптимизатор_ делает раскрутку циклов. Я понял ваш вопрос именно так. А какой пример вы хотели на самом деле?

Comment: @Majestio: Кстати, обратите внимание, что с текущими процессорами раскрутка циклов вполне может быть _медленнее_ (из-за того, что хуже используется предиктор переходов, и размер кода растёт, а значит, чаще приходится обновлять кэш), поэтому на сегодняшний день компиляторы чаще всего **не применяют** раскрутку циклов.

Comment: Ну правильный (читаем "классический") пример "размотки" на 490 итераций.

Comment: если вы про кэши камней ... да, возможно, но ИМХО надо погонять тесты. Не уверен что по докам будет возможно что-то ванговать уверенно. Это ИМХО.

Comment: @Majestio: Правильная размотка делается не программистом, а компилятором. Если вы заглянете в мой пример на godbolt, там в C/С++-коде обыкновенный, стандартный цикл, а в ассемблерном коде полный аналог duff's device. Его создал не программист, а оптимизирующий компилятор. (И у меня там не 490, а `num`.)

Comment: @Majestio: По поводу кешей, статья в википедии ссылается на [вот это поучительное обсуждение](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0008.2/0171.html): после отказа от размотки циклов размер X-сервера уменьшился на пол-метра, а скорость загрузки возросла.

Comment: У меня с английским слабовато, но текст в основном осознал. Сенкс. Обсуждение закрывается ... ну как минимум для меня) Пасип!

Comment: @Majestio: Если ещё появятся вопросы по теме, приходите в [чат по C/C++](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26298/c-c).

Comment: @Majestio: Пожалуйста! Рад, что обсуждение оказалось полезным.

Answer (score 5):

> Почему сия конструкция иногда (или часто?) дает профит.

Данная конструкция "дает профит" потому, что уменьшает количество условных переходов в программе по сравнению с тривиальной реализацией того же цикла

```
for (int c = 10; c > 0; --c)
  foo();
```

Подразумевается, что тривиальная реализация будет странслирована в машинный код "один-в-один", т.е. будет проверять условие продолжения цикла после каждой из 10 итераций. Толковая "развернутая по четыре" реализация проверяет условие продолжения своего цикла только 3 раза (`10 / 4` с округлением вверх).

Надо заметить, что у вас получилась слегка "некачественная" реализация Duff's Device, которая иногда делает на одну проверку больше, чем классическая реализация. Например для случая `c = 4` ваш код сделает две проверки условия цикла, в то время как классическое Duff's Device - только одну.

(Умиляет также "пионерская оптимизация" с заменой `% 4` на `& 3`.)

Comment: Хм .. а почему "пионерская оптимизация"? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Отсекать "ненужное" так же понятнее или не? И самое главное ... расскажите про "некачественность", это самое важное. Для туземцев, на пальцах)

Comment: @Majestio: Для случая `c = 4` ваш код сделает две проверки условия цикла, в то время как классическое Duff's Device - только одну. Вот и весь рассказ.

Comment: прошу привести "классическое" ... дабы сравнить. Пока просто "плаваю", а любопытство - оно такое))

Comment: @Majestio: Код здесь: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff's_device